# Get redirect url after POST with AJAX (Spring Social)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social and it has a controller on /signin/facebook, which can be used with POST request to build a facebook oauth link for the user.

It goes like this -

1. I submit POST request with data to the /signin/facebook
2. Then it gets redirected to the facebook link
3. When I click on the link from the dev console, it gets redirected back to /signin/facebook?authdata....

If there is no better way to do this, I want at least get the redirect link from step 2. No idea how to do that. This is what I get with my current code "{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}".

My code is :

```
var csrf = $("#csrf").val();
var scope = $("#scope").val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {_csrf: csrf, scope: scope},
                url: "/signin/facebook",
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
                }
            });
```

Comment: In your complete ajax method, you could check for a valid http response code or status code (200?), if successfully signed in, then do a window.location = "http://www.yourpage.com"; to re-direct the user after successful login..

Comment: @Woodrow but I always get {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"} and  "Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)". After I do the POST, the request gets redirected to facebook and it is 303